# What causes a partial view to not run controller actions

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have no idea what happened but suddenly the CRUD operations in my simple app no longer work. Clicking on the create button in my partial view, instead of running the controller create action, now looks for a create page instead. Not really sure what would cause this all I did was sleep.

Index

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
       
                <div class="card-title">  
                     <h1>Clients</h1>
    <div id="showmodal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                @{
                   @await Html.PartialAsync("_CreateClient");
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id='open' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showmodal">Add New Client</button>
        </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

Partial View

```
@model Rabbit.Application.Models.Onboarding.Client

 
                         <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Add Client Overview Record</h5>
                        <button type="button" id='close' class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                   
<form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Client")">
     <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="modal-body">          
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-lg-4">  
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CompanyName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CompanyName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ContactPerson" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ContactPerson" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ContactPerson" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SuiteNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SuiteNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SuiteNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>




            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">

                            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="City" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="State" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="State" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ZipCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ZipCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ZipCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
          

           


            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" onclick="return processData()" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
               @* <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;"/>*@
            </div>
            </div>
         
               </div>

              </div>

                </div>        

                       
          </form>
     

          @section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

          
        });

    </script>
}
```

Controller

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Onboarding/Client/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("VID,CompanyName,PhoneNo,ContactPerson,Email,Address,SuiteNo,City,State,ZipCode")] Client client)
        {

                _context.Add(client);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            
            return View(client);
        }
```

Comment: You mean the button `<input type="submit" onclick="return processData()" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />`?If so can you share the code of `processData()`?

Comment: I ended up getting the button to work. Was a typo for that. Thanks for the help! Now onto my next issues haha